# Web sites / systems that uses LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm doing a question where I need to find out actual web systems that uses LINQ.
Anyone have any ideas what sites uses LINQ? and the evidence that shows that it uses LINQ.
Thanks!

Comment: The term _LINQ_ is a bit vague. Any professional .NET developer will most likely use the functional operators defined in the `System.Linq` namespace in some part of the code meaning a great number of websites "uses" LINQ. However, perhaps you are investigating _LINQ to SQL_ which provides a way to access relational data in .NET? This technology is no longer actively being developed by Microsoft that instead provides the _Entity Framework_ for data access.

Comment: Yeah that probably is it. The question asks to "find an actual web system that implemented the technology (in my case, LINQ) and elaborate in detail". That's probably mean I need to find any web system that uses either LINQ to SQL, LINQ to XML, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ThinqLinq.com uses LINQ heavily, has source available, and multiple blog posts indicating how LINQ is used in pieces of the site. It is NOT designed for high scalability. It's more of a proof of concept and playground for test ideas. The biggest LINQ to SQL implementation I know of is Stack. I think they have discussed some of the optimizations they did to improve performance in some of their early podcasts, but don't know which ones off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is one example of such site.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But is there any evidence that shows that this website uses LINQ?

Comment: @William Edwin Sieh, StackOverflow is not open source so the only evidence is blog posts such as this one from its creators: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/